# Irreducibility of a certain polynomial in an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $k[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ be a polynomial ring. Show that $x_1x_3-x_2^2$ is irreducible in $k[x_1,x_2,x_3]$.

I viewed the polynomial $x_1x_3-x_2^2$ as a polynomial in $k[x_1x_3][x_2]=k[x_2][x_1x_3]$. Then it is a polynomial of degree $1$ in $k[x_2][x_1x_3]$. But how do I show that this is equivalent to $x_1x_3-x_2$ being irreducible in $k[x_1,x_2,x_3]$

Comment: You seem to switch from $x_1x_3-x_2^2$ to $x_1x_3-x_2$. But in any event, can't you just say your original polynomial has total degree two, so if it vactors it must be a product of polynomials of degree one, and then rule that out?

Comment: Any thoughts on my comments, TAO?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: Actually, I can quite catch your point